# Decrypt the encrypted pdf file having text and image content, using CryptoJS AES encryption javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, cryptojs

Trying to encrypt a pdf file having text and image content using cryptojs AES algo. after decryption the decrypted content is not same in a way the image content within pdf is different but text part is same as expected.

This is project requirement to first encrypt pdf file containing text and image and send to server(JAVA). on retrieval get the encrypted file and decrypt it.

On decryption expecting to have same file content as before encryption.

```
encryptFile(file): Promise<string> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const reader = new FileReader();

const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('u/Gu5posvwDsXUnV5Zaq4g==');
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('5D9r9ZVzEYYgha93/aUK2w==');

reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    const utf8Stringified = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(reader.result)
    const encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(utf8Stringified, key, { iv: 
    iv,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC })
    resolve(CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(encrypted.ciphertext))
};
reader.readAsText(file);
})
}

decryptFile(file): Promise<string> {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()

    const key = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('u/Gu5posvwDsXUnV5Zaq4g==');
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse('5D9r9ZVzEYYgha93/aUK2w==');

    reader.onloadend = function (e) {
    const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(reader.result, key, { iv: iv, 
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC })
    resolve(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8))
};
reader.readAsText(file);
})
}
```

Comment: You treat the pdf as a utf8-encoded text file, e.g. at `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(reader.result)`. But it isn't utf8-encoded, it isn't even a text file, it is a binary file by nature! Thus, this will damage the pdf. Encrypt and decrypt as binary data!

Comment: It still shows the same result, convert some of content like Ãž to � might be some issue of encoding of different type of content in pdf. Due to this on opening the pdf file shows error: "not a pdf or corrupted"